# gradient of $x^tAy$ with respect of $y$ and gradient of the Euclidean norm.

Tags: matrices, derivatives, differential-forms

I was reading [this paper](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2010/11/2790.pdf) where they want to find the saddle point of this equation:

$$\text{min }\text{max }\{x^TAy + \frac{\lambda}{2} ||By−z||^2\}$$

Where $x,y,z$ are vectors and $A,B$ are matrices. $\lambda$ is a real number.

On section 2.1 they reformulate this problem as a Variational Inequality. [I read here (page 2332)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9af7/acccacd05d5f7274c4ffce903648a1824e34.pdf) that is easier to consider variational inequalities of the function's differentials, so the authors of the first paper (I'll call it "the paper of doom") make:

$$\Delta_x (x^TAy + \frac{\lambda}{2} ||By−z||^2) = -A^Ty \tag{1}$$
$$\Delta_y (x^TAy + \frac{\lambda}{2} ||By−z||^2) = Ax + \lambda B^T(By - z) \tag{2}$$

I assume that $\Delta_x (||By−z||^2) = 0$.

I'm calculating $\Delta_y(||By−z||^2)$ as follows:

$$\Delta_y(||By−z||^2) = \Delta_y \sum_i^L \sum_j^N (b_{ij}y_j - z_j)^2$$
$$ = \Delta_y \sum_i^L \sum_j^N |(b_{ij}y_j)^2 - 2b_{ij}y_jz_j + z_j^2|$$
$$ = \sum_i^L \sum_j^N \Delta_y |(b_{ij}y_j)^2 - 2b_{ij}y_jz_j + z_j^2|$$
$$ = \sum_i^L \sum_j^N |2b_{ij}y_j - 2b_{ij}z_j|$$
$$ = 2\sum_i^L \sum_j^N |b_{ij}y_j - b_{ij}z_j|$$

After reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/709686/154124) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482742/154124) I'm calculating the derivatives of $y^TAx$ as follows: (typo here, see the edit)

**Edit:**

Thanks Greg for your comment, you helped me to find a typo in my question and other mistakes from the authors [of the paper of doom](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2010/11/2790.pdf), here's the correction:

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{LxN}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{L}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$.

I'm calculating the derivatives of $x^TAy$ as follows:

$$\Delta_x x^TAy = Ay$$
$$\Delta_y x^TAy = x^TA$$

[Thanks to this wonderful paper](https://atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf), I knew that my calculation of $\Delta_x x^TAy$ and $\Delta_y x^TAy$ were right, in the case of $\Delta_x x^TAy$ I was missing a last step:
$$\Delta_y x^TAy = x^TA = a \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$a = a^T = (x^TA)^T = A^Tx$$

For the euclidean norm, [in the paper of doom](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2010/11/2790.pdf) authors make (or at least seem to make, I can not trust them anymore):

$$\frac{\lambda}{2} ||By−z||^2 = \lambda B^T(By−z)$$

Where $z \in \mathbb{R}^L, B \in \mathbb{R}^{LxN}$

My mistake was trying to force my results to look like the ones in the paper of doom. How to calculate the derivative of the euclidean norm is well explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/818467/154124) and more closely to my case [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/291328/154124). $(By)_i$ is the $i$ element of the vector $By$, and $y_i$ is the $i$ element of the vector $y$:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}||By - z||^2 = 2(\sum_i^L ((By_i) - z_i)) \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}((By)_i - z_i) $$

So I'm getting:

$$\Delta_x (x^TAy + \frac{\lambda}{2} ||By−z||^2) = Ay \tag{3}$$
$$\Delta_y (x^TAy + \frac{\lambda}{2} ||By−z||^2) = A^Tx + 2(\sum_i^L ((By_i) - z_i)) \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}((By)_i - z_i) \tag{4}$$

At this point, I'm unsure how to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}((By)_i - z_i)$ Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I don't know what to make of the first paper. Their very first equation is defines 
$$\eqalign{
&\Phi(x,y) = x^TAy + \frac{\lambda}{2}\|By-z\|^2 \cr
 &x\in{\mathbb R}^{L},\,
 y\in{\mathbb R}^{N},\,
 z\in{\mathbb R}^{L},\,
 A\in{\mathbb R}^{L\times N},\,
 B\in{\mathbb R}^{L\times N} \cr
}$$
But in section 2.1 they start writing stuff like
$$(x-x^*)^T(-A^Ty)\ge 0$$ Nevermind the accuracy of their differentials and gradients, this is just dimensionally incompatible nonsense.

Comment: @greg, you're right, authors messed with dimensions horribly. Their $-A^Ty$ has no sense unless $L=N$. Thanks a lot for making me notice it.

Comment: They also mess with dimensions where they make $(y-y^*)^T(Ax^* + \lambda B^T(By^*−z)$